# Change the date format of meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Is there a way to change the format of `aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker` to `dd/mm/yyyy`. I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
date: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            datePickerOptions:
                {
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                }
          }
    }
```

Comment: The option to change the date format for the jQuery UI datepicker widget is `dateFormat`, not `format`. Theoretically that should work... http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Thanks Brian, unfortunately that doesn't work either. What's strange is if I don't use the aldeed:meteor-autoform-bs-datepicker I don't have this problem.

Comment: Also having this problem. Any update?

Comment: Never figured this one out. Still stuck on it. If you have any luck please update here.

Answer (score 0):

the format

```
d/mm/yyyy
```

would return

```
22/12/2015
```

Alternatively, the format

```
D/mm/yyyy
```

would return

```
Saturday/12/2015
```

Check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's a better idea to quote the article you linked to rather than just giving a link. What if the article disappears and the link starts redirecting to a 404?